# How to create a view of Media images that do not have any Alt Text

Tags: 8, views, media

For accessibility purposes I want to create a view of Media images that do not have any Alt Text.

Creating a view of Media images and also displaying Alt Text is not difficult, as explained is this d.o post [Media alt text not available in Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2960415)

However I do not know of a way to create a filter of 'Alt Text is NULL' so that a view can be built which only returns images without alt text.

Any suggestions for how could this be accomplished? Ideally this would be a view of media entities so that other filters relating to media can also be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the Filter called `Thumbnail (alt)` from the Media Category that is for the Alt text.

After you add the Relationship for the Image field the `Is empty (NULL)` Operator will become available. If the Relationship is not present only the string operators will be listed.

Add the Relationship `image from field_media_image` and then add the `Thumbnail (alt)` Filter with the `Is empty (NULL)` Operator.

It will filter out Media items that have the Alt field available in their structure but not filled in (empty), for example images, as opposed to Files that don't come with Alt fields in their structure.

---

On the other hand, using the `Is less than 1` Operator/value combination can help in situations when you need to filter out different Media types to show the items that don't have the Alt field in their structure at all like File types, while Images with empty alt don't satisfy that condition.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @prkos, but unfortunately this is not working out for me. The field certainly works for less than 30, 20, or 5. But I find it does not return images with no alt text based on less than 1. In the d.o link mentioned above, post #9 suggests there is something amiss with Thumbnail Alt. Could this be the reason I am having problems? I am able to reproduce this on simplytes.me - independently of my local environment.

Comment: I tried it, it is working for me. Are you sure you're doing it inside Media type, and not Content Views type? I'm trying on simplytest.me now

Comment: Please try this saved instance on simplytesme https://stm609cd9ca112ed-dxlwq4fmkdzqaowliqlv5rf8e4g9aeh8.tugboat.qa/ The link won't last forever but is good for a few hours I think. If it does go dead, I have also exported the view as a pastebin at https://pastebin.com/vt96byVm

Comment: My experience is that Thumbnail Alt renders with an image formatter. To expose the alt text it is neccessary to rewrite the field. The filter for shorter than 1 does not appear to work, but greater than 1 does. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Solved it! Thank you for providing the tugboat, I edited your version and got the same result as you! I compared it with my local example and the difference is that in my Media the Alt text is Required (in Media Image Manage Fields settings). After a lightbulb moment I realized my Views example was filtering out File type media, not Image media with empty Alt. So the issue is about the types and I'm guessing how Null is different from zero. My answer was wrong! I'll update it.

Comment: PPS You must add the Relationship for the Image for the Null operators to become available! I'm sorry I missed it earlier, I was looking at the wrong Media Views clone when writing the answer.

Comment: Another project has been keeping me very busy, so my sincere apologies for the delay in reporting back. I tried your solution and it works perfectly. Marking as my chosen answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad to help :)